# aws amplify codegen - Language swift not supported

Tags: swift, swiftui, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

Currently working on an iOS SwiftUI Project in combination with AWS Amplify. After a reinstall of amplify cli the `amplify pull` command stopped producing the swift code for my models.

Using the command `amplify codegen` I get the error `Language swift not supported`.

I can't explain why this is happening, before the reinstall it worked perfectly fine.

```
.graphqlconfig.yml 

projects:   
  placeholder:     
    schemaPath: graphql/schema.json     
    includes:
       - graphql/**/*.graphql     
    excludes:
       - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
       amplify:
         codeGenTarget: swift
         generatedFileName: API.swift
         docsFilePath: graphql
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```

I tried to reconfigure codegen with `amplify configure codegen` but it only shows languages typescript, flow and javascript ... not swift.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, never mind solved it. Had to manually adjust project-config.json in the amplify/.config/project-config.json file. Insert frontend 'ios'.

Comment: You should add that as an answer if it solved your issue